# To retreive sharepoint list data using client context

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sharepoint

I am trying to retrieve Sharepoint list data using Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client library using vb.net windows form.

Below is the vb.net code for reference.

```
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

Public Class sharepoint_list
    Private client_context As ClientContext

    Private Sub sharepoint_list_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        client_context = New ClientContext("siteurl@user.com")
        Dim web_ As Web = client_context.Web
        client_context.Credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@user.com", GetPassword("user@user.com", "mypass@123"))
        client_context.Load(web_)
        client_context.ExecuteQuery()
        MsgBox(web_.Title)

    End Sub

    Public Function GetPassword(username As String, password As String) As Security.SecureString
        Dim keyinfo As ConsoleKeyInfo
        Dim securePass As Security.SecureString
        securePass = New Security.SecureString
        For Each c As Char In password
            securePass.AppendChar(keyinfo.KeyChar)
        Next
        Return securePass
    End Function
End Class
```

Whenever I try to run this piece of code, It throws an error with the following message

> '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.

and the following message on the console

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred
>   in System.Xml.dll

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the GetPassword method as below:

```
Public Function GetPassword(password As String) As Security.SecureString
        Dim securePass As Security.SecureString
        securePass = New Security.SecureString
        For Each c As Char In password
            securePass.AppendChar(c)
        Next
        Return securePass
End Function
```

Change the line of code below

```
client_context.Credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@user.com", GetPassword("user@user.com", "mypass@123"))
```

to

```
client_context.Credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@user.com", GetPassword("mypass@123"))
```

Comment: It gave me following error 'The partner returned a bad sign-in name or password error. For more information, see Federation Error-handling Scenarios.'

Comment: check the name and password, for SharePoint Online, the login name like: test@lz.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: I have logged onto SharePoint online using same username and password, but no success

Comment: If you use third party use, the code will not works.